# Error while implementing cross-validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I am trying to evaluate a model(MNIST) using cross-validation:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.base import clone
skfolds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42)
```

while running 3rd line I get this warning:

> C:\Users\nextg\Desktop\sample_project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_split.py:293:
> FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is
> False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state
> to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.   warnings.warn(

Ignoring the warning I write this code

```
for train_index, test_index in skfolds.split(X_train, y_test_5):
   clone_clf = clone(sgd_clf)
   X_train_folds = X_train[train_index]
   y_train_folds = y_train[train_index]
   X_test_fold = X_test[test_index]
   y_test_fold = y_test_5[test_index]

   clone_clf.fit(X_train_folds, y_train_folds)
   y_pred = clone_clf.predict(X_test_fold)
   n_correct = sum(y_pred == y_test_fold)
   print(n_correct / len(y_pred))
```

After running this code the error is

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-7e786591c439> in <module>
 ----> 1 for train_index, test_index in skfolds.split(X_train, y_test_5):
  2     clone_clf = clone(sgd_clf)
  3     X_train_folds = X_train[train_index]
  4     y_train_folds = y_train[train_index]
  5     X_test_fold = X_test[test_index]

 ~\Desktop\sample_project\env\lib\site- 
 packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
     326             The testing set indices for that split.
     327         """
 --> 328         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
     329         n_samples = _num_samples(X)
     330         if self.n_splits > n_samples:

   ~\Desktop\sample_project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    291     """
    292     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 293     check_consistent_length(*result)
    294     return result
    295 

 ~\Desktop\sample_project\env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    254     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    255     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 256         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
257                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
258 

 ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [60000, 10000]
```

Can somebody help to solve the error

Comment: Where exactly does the error pop up - in `fit` or in `predict`? Please update your question with the full trace.

Comment: Thank you to answer. The problem is in 3rd line of code before fit or predict. Model is already working. By this code I am trying to evaluate my model. while evaluating i got Future warning.

Comment: Please *specify exactly* in the question. I am talking about the error, *not* the warning (which is self-explainable).

Comment: I have updated full error. Should I write the whole MNIST model for better understanding the error.

Answer (score 1):

Its works:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.base import clone

skfolds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

for train_index, test_index in skfolds.split(X_train, y_train_5):  
    clone_clf = clone(sgd_clf)
    X_train_folds = X_train.values[train_index]
    y_train_folds = y_train_5[train_index]
    X_test_fold = X_train.values[test_index]
    y_test_fold = y_train_5[test_index]
    
    clone_clf.fit(X_train_folds, y_train_folds)
    y_pred = clone_clf.predict(X_test_fold)
    n_correct = sum(y_pred == y_test_fold)
    print(n_correct / len(y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression does not make sense: `skfolds.split(X_train, y_test_5)`.

It should be `skfolds.split(X, y)` with `X.shape[0] == y.shape[0]`

From the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html):

```py
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `skfolds.split(X_train, y_train_5)` not `skfolds.split(X_train, y_test_5)`
and in 2nd line of for loop its `y_test_fold = y_train_5[test_index]` not `y_train_folds = y_train[train_index]`

The whole problem begun because of tab key.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code and assuming that you split (by yourself the data), you are looping into X_train and y_test_5.

And for the error that you obtained you have have 6000 samples for the train and 1000 samples for the test. That's why have the error (different matrix sizes(shapes)).

Note: Never fit the test data to Classifier, this will overfit the data (the ML algorythm will already know the images, and it will make the algorythm useless).

Hope it helps!!!